# user input not being saved when using functions in tkinter

Tags: python, function, input, tkinter

i am calling a function within a function to try and print input entered by the user. When I call the ultra() function it works and successfully prints the user input, but when I call the package() function, which calls the ultra function in it, it prints blank and does not work. what am i doing wrong?

```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter

    def package():
        global IDVar
        window=tkinter.Tk()
        window.title('Lightning Parties')

        lbl_package=tkinter.Label(window, text='Please click on the Package you would like!', fg='white', bg='purple', font=('comicsans', 10))
        lbl_package.pack()

        lbl=tkinter.Button(window, text='Ultra',command=ultra)
        lbl.pack()

     def ultra():
        import tkinter
        global IDVar
        win = Tk()
        win.wm_title("Lightning Parties Validating")
        frame1=Frame(win)
        frame1.pack()
        Label(frame1, text="Lightning Parties - Validating", font=("Helvetica 12 bold")).grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(frame1, text="ID").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        IDVar=StringVar()
        title= Entry(frame1, textvariable=IDVar)
        title.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
        frame2 = Frame(win)
        frame2.pack()
        b1= Button(frame2, text="continue ", command=save)
        b1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
        def save():
            global ID
            ID = IDVar.get()
            print ('here is', ID)    


    package()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, create an instance of `Toplevel`.